# create a file with name using php form

Tags: php

Filling a form wich gave two parts, filename and text i need to create a file in the html directory wich will have name $filename and get the text inside it that i put in $text.
unfortinatly i cant make it work
any help please:

FORM CODE:

```
<form method="post" action="createfile.php">
<font size"3"><b>File name:</b> </font>
<br /><input type="text" size="15" name="filename" id="filename"><br />
<font size"3"><b>File data:</b> </font>
<div id="dat"><textarea name="thedata" id="thedata" cols="30" rows="15"></textarea></div>
<div id="sub" style="position:absolute; left: 25">
<input type="submit" value=" Create ">
</div>
</form>
```

the createfile.php CODE:

```
<?php 
$name= $filename; 
$data= $thedata; 
if ( $file && $data ) { 
$fp = fopen($file, "w");  
fwrite($fp, "<br>"); 
fwrite($fp, $data); 
fclose($fp); 
} 
else 
{ echo 'no text entered'; 
} 
?>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: "unfortinatly i cant make it work any help please" Is really not a problem description.

Comment: In case you haven't thought of it, you should realize that anybody could use this code to overwrite whatever files your webserver's user has access to. This is a pretty big security nightmare. What if somebody supplies a file like `createfile.php` and overwrites your own website?

Comment: i supose this is my problem. i have htaccess on the dir. ;)

Comment: No need to use `fopen` + `fwrite` + `fclose`, use `file_put_contents` instead : http://php.net/file_put_contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML will be same:

```
<form method="post" action="createfile.php">
<font size"3"><b>File name:</b> </font>
<br /><input type="text" size="15" name="filename" id="filename"><br />
<font size"3"><b>File data:</b> </font>
<div id="dat"><textarea name="thedata" id="thedata" cols="30" rows="15"></textarea></div>
<div id="sub" style="position:absolute; left: 25">
<input type="submit" value=" Create ">
</div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$content  = $_POST['thedata'] ;
$if(!isset($_POST['filename'])){
    //i leave the filename && content validation to the client side

    $handle = fopen("/files/$filename.txt", "w");
    fwrite($handle, $content);
    fclose($handle);
}else{
    //your `else` code here.
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked fine.
So now I would like to execute command for that created file, so i make a command 
<?php
// Change cfg to bin
echo exec('/usr/local/bin/fix -p $txt $bin');
?>
which will change the .txt file to a .bin file and save it again to the same directory? 

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
<?php
$name= isset($_POST['filename'])?$_POST['filename']:0; 
$data= isset($_POST['thedata'])?$_POST['thedata']:0;  
if ($name && $data ) { 
$fp = fopen($name, "w");  
fwrite($fp, "<br>"); 
fwrite($fp, $data); 
fclose($fp); 
} 
else { 
echo 'no text entered'; 
} 
?>
```